# Federation/SSO techniques

Tags: security, single-sign-on, saml, federated-identity, federation

I am wondering about techniques to implement federation across a group of public websites. The simple answer is 'federation' or 'saml'. However, in practice I can see lots of technical problems: creating account linkages (so that user "SteveRoy" in site1 is linked to "SRoy" in site2), changing logon pages to reference a central IdP, dealing with users that don't have accounts across all the sites, dealing with session logout across sites etc. etc.    In short, it seems like 'saml' is an oversimplification of a much more complex issue. Would love to hear details from those who have succeeded in this space...

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the answer you are hoping for, but here goes. :)

SAML (and related/alternative OpenID), is just a protocol used to pass assertions about identity and federate that authentication decision somewhere else - it lets you accept the word of a service (IdP) you trust to perform user authentication for you. These protocols ALLOW you to build a federated identity system; they are NOT such a system by themselves.

Everything you mention in your question (user mapping, the actual SP infrastructure maintenance, individual site authorization, federated logout) have been, and remain, challenges in this area and any solution you deploy out there does need to address of these engineering/implementation questions. You could, and someone probably should, write hundreds of pages on the various ways of approaching all of nuances involved in building an effective federated identity system. There are no easy answers in this space.